# facebook sharing - override OpenGraph meta tags?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sharer

trying to share something. Website got opengraph meta data, but I want to share dynamic content - so a custom text for each user. Passing it via the sharer.php, in the "Share link" popup im creating it all looks fine, but on the user's wall it suddenly shows the opengraph meta data again.

Any way to do this, or do I have to create an fb Application and use FB.ui?